# making backgroundImage property from material UI themes dynamic

Tags: arrays, reactjs, image, dynamic, material-ui

I have a CSS-oriented problem. I need to render a list of cards with the background faded so that it's semi-transparent with overlayed text that is non-transparent. I've shared two images below:

The first image accomplishes exactly what I want to do (as the background blur does not blur the overlay text), but the problem is I used material UI themes (I think that's what it's called) and I can't figure out how to make the backgroundImage property hold dynamic values for those. How can I make backgroundImage dynamic so that I get all of the images like in the second pic? Something like this, which I tried but doesn't work: `{classes.categoryCard.backgroundImage =`url(${el.image})`}`

Note: The problem with the second screen shot is that I'm using an image tag to get the pics, which makes it easier to render the images, dynamically but I can't separated the blur from the overlay text that way.

code from the component:

```
// images
import deals from "../assets/deals.jpg";
import breakfast from "../assets/breakfast.jpg";
import fastfood from "../assets/fastfood.jpg";
import mexican from "../assets/mexican.jpg";
import vegan from "../assets/vegan.jpg";
import american from "../assets/american.jpg";
import healthy from "../assets/healthy.jpg";
import chinese from "../assets/chinese.jpg";
import pizza from "../assets/pizza.jpg";
import coffee from "../assets/coffee.jpg";
const categoryArr = [
    {category: 'Latest Deals', image: deals},
    {category: 'Breakfast and Brunch', image: breakfast},
    {category: 'Fast Food', image: fastfood},
    {category: 'Mexican', image: mexican},
    {category: 'Vegan', image: vegan},
    {category: 'American', image: american},
    {category: 'Healthy', image: healthy},
    {category: 'Pizza', image: pizza},
    {category: 'Chinese', image: chinese},
    {category: 'Coffee and Tea', image: coffee},
]
const DineSearch = props => {
    // const [trucksByType, setTrucksByType] = useState([]);
    const useStyles = makeStyles({
            categoryCard: {
                backgroundImage: `url(${chinese})`,
                backgroundSize: 'cover',
                backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
                height: 200,
            }
          });
    const classes = useStyles();
    const selectCategory = (category) => {
        props.getTrucksByCuisine(category)
            .then(props.history.push(`/diner/${props.dinerId}`))
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>This is the Dine Search component</h1>
            <Grid className="category-grid" container spacing={1}>
                {categoryArr.map(el => (
                    <Grid item xs={6}>
                        <Card className={classes.categoryCard} onClick={() => selectCategory(el.category)}>
                                <div className="category-image-wrapper">
                                <CardMedia
                                    className="category-image"
                                    // image={el.image}
                                />
                                </div>
                                <div className="category-text-wrapper">
                                <Typography className="category-text" component="h2">
                                    {el.category}
                                </Typography>
                                </div>
                        </Card>
                    </Grid>
                ))}
            </Grid>
            <DinerFooter />
        </div>
    )
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: backgroundImage: `url(${chinese})` looks dynamic to me, is that not working?

Comment: That's hard coded to show the image for Chinese food. I need the array to be mapped through so that each card shows the image for that respective food category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working by using inline styling.

```
<Card 
className={classes.categoryCard} 
style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${el.image})` }} 
onClick={() => selectCategory(el.category)}
>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could try passing the image as the prop `backgroundImage`:

```
<CardMedia
    className="category-image"
    backgroundImage={el.image}
/>
```

Then, in the `CardMedia` component's file, attach some inline CSS based on that passed in prop in the `style` prop of whatever DOM element you have in there (I'm using a `<div>`):

```
function CardMedia(props) {
  return (
    <div style={{
      backgroundImage: props.backgroundImage,
    }}>
    { /* implement the rest of the card...*/ } 
    </div>
  );
}
```